# Manage Two different ids with different auto-increment in Doctrine?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a table named vouchers and there is an id which is an auto-increment. and I want to add a voucher number which should be auto increment also but with relation to the user.
eg:

| Name | id | userId | voucher |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| eg1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| eg2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| eg3 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| eg3 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| eg4 | 5 | 1 | 3 |

Comment: What purpose does the voucher number serve that it has to incrememted in a group? Group-wise auto increments are something extremely difficult to create in a multi-user environment.

Comment: yes, group-wise auto-increment is exactly what I want.  I can do this by first running a query to search the last voucher id from the group and adding one to it and store it. but that is slowing down my process.

Comment: As [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) states in his [SQL Antipatterns](https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557) book, "Do not try solving a complex problem in one step instead of two.".

Comment: You still have not answered why you want a group wise auto increment! If it is for identification purposes, then just forget it. If it is for sorting / display purposes, forget it again and calculate ranking on the fly.

Comment: I want group-wise increment because I will have multiple companies registered with me and when they submit a voucher they will have voucher id that should not be affected even if other users submit their own vouchers.

Comment: voucher id is for just the organization's clerical work and some government compliance, not for the backend.